# Why getMimeType() is returning wrong value for xlsx file

Tags: files

Below is my 2 line code to get the Mime Type of an attachment in a preprocess function

```
$file = $node->get('field_attachment_file')->entity;
$variables['attach_type'] = $file->getMimeType();
```

The $variables['attach_type'] is always getting the value of 'application/pdf' despite the attachment being an Microsoft Excel spreadsheet

Comment: Is the file extension correct? If the filename is example.xlsx.pdf, it would think it is a PDF file.

Comment: yes the file extension is correct. It's example.xlsx

Answer (score 2):

The value returned as MIME type of a file is the value returned from the [*file.mime_type.guesser*](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21core.services.yml/service/file.mime_type.guesser/8.7.x) service which, on a default Drupal installation, uses three classes to guess the MIME type:

- The [`ExtensionMimeTypeGuesser`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21File%21MimeType%21ExtensionMimeTypeGuesser.php/class/ExtensionMimeTypeGuesser/8.7.x) class (a Drupal core class) guesses it from the file extension, but it doesn't have a mapping for the .xlsx files, for which it returns *application/octet-stream* (See [`ExtensionMimeTypeGuesser::guess()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21File%21MimeType%21ExtensionMimeTypeGuesser.php/function/ExtensionMimeTypeGuesser%3A%3Aguess/8.7.x) and [`ExtensionMimeTypeGuesser::$defaultMapping`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21File%21MimeType%21ExtensionMimeTypeGuesser.php/property/ExtensionMimeTypeGuesser%3A%3AdefaultMapping/8.7.x).)
- The [`FileBinaryMimeTypeGuesser`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/vendor%21symfony%21http-foundation%21File%21MimeType%21FileBinaryMimeTypeGuesser.php/class/FileBinaryMimeTypeGuesser/8.7.x) class (a Symfony class) returns the output of `file -b --mime <filename> 2>/dev/null`
- The [`FileinfoMimeTypeGuesser`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/vendor%21symfony%21http-foundation%21File%21MimeType%21FileinfoMimeTypeGuesser.php/class/FileinfoMimeTypeGuesser/8.7.x) class (a Symfony class) returns the output of [`finfo_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php)

It is also possible that a module implements [`hook_file_mimetype_mapping_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21File%21file.api.php/function/hook_file_mimetype_mapping_alter/8.7.x) to change the value returned from the first class, the file used from `file` or `fileinfo_file()` contains the wrong values, or another module implements another guesser class that is used before the other classes and returns the wrong MIME type.

Comment: So is it safe to assume it's an issue with core?

Comment: [Office 2007 File Format MIME Types for HTTP Content Streaming](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsofficedeveloper/2008/05/08/office-2007-file-format-mime-types-for-http-content-streaming-2/) suggests that the correct MIME type for .xlsx files should be application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet. The Drupal core issue is not having an explicit mapping for those files. I cannot say you get *application/pdf* because a core bug.